# How to render back form errors to a template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

so I'm dead new to MeteorJS, and am implementing error handling for a form. I'm using the simple-validation so I get a list of error keys and an error message.

Is there a way I can return them in the controller event handler, so that I can just evaluate them in a {{}} tag?

Let's say I have a simplified handler

```
//New thread form on forum page
Template.forum_details.events({
  "submit .new-thread": function (event) {
     var errors = [{field: 'title',error: 'title is required'}]


    // Prevent default form submit
    return false;
  }
});
```

Can I render these errors in the template, or do I need to use jquery/etc?

I was hoping to be able to just modify the template data and evaluate with e,g.

{{#each errors}}

### Edit:

Thanks to the answer below, I was able to come up with the following, which works great!

errors.js:

```
throwError = function(field,message) {  
    //format the 'required' error type to make it look a little more readable...    
    if(message == 'required')
    {
        message = field + " is required.";  
    }
  Errors.insert({field:field,message: message});
};
if (Meteor.isClient) {


Template.errors.helpers({
  errors: function() {
    return Errors.find();
  }
});

Template.registerHelper('hasError', 
    function(key)
    {
        //console.log("Checking for key:" + key);
        if(Errors.find({field:key}).count() > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
);


Template.error.helpers({
    //Return the error for the specified key
    error:  function(key)
    {
    return Errors.findOne({field:key});
    },
    message: function(key)
    {
        //console.log("Finding message for key: " + key);
        //console.log(key);
        Errors.findOne({field:key}).message;
        return Errors.findOne({field:key}).message;
    }   
}); 
}
```

Errors.html

```
<template name="errors">
  <div class="errors">
    {{#each errors}}
      {{> error}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="error">

{{#if hasError key }}
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    {{message key}}
  </div>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Then in my actual forms, I call it like this:

```
<div class="form-group title">
    <label for="title">Thread Title</label>
    <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Thread Title" />
      <span class="help-block title" name="title"></span>

        {{>error  key='title'}}          
  </div>
```

This will show an error message if exists, and nothing if it doesn't.

Further can make a template for a textbox, textarea, numeric input etc by passing in the 'key' for the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can manage the errors like this (i take the code from [Discover Meteor Erros Chapter](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=es&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=es&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fes.discovermeteor.com%2Fchapters%2Ferrors%2F&edit-text=).)

**First** Create a new empty collection

```
Errors = new Mongo.Collection(null); //we use the keyword null, when we don't want the data get stored on the database
```

**Second** Create this function.

```
throwError = function(message) {
  Errors.insert({message: message});
};
```

**Third**. Call the template name using the {{>}} yield helper

```
<template name="layoutExample">
  <div class="container">
    {{> header}}
    {{> errors}} <!-- Here or whatever you want to top the error messages -->
    <div id="main" class="row-fluid">
      {{> yield}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Four** Create the errors template with this data.

```
<template name="errors">
  <div class="errors">
    {{#each errors}}
      {{> error}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="error">
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    {{message}}
  </div>
</template>
```

And don't forget about the `errors` helper

```
Template.errors.helpers({
  errors: function() {
    return Errors.find();
  }
});
```

**Five** and Last Testing.

```
throwError("I'm an error!");
```

No you can use it over the app on the callbacks or whatever you can throw erros.

Example.

```
 Example.insert({dummyData:"im a dummy"},function(err,result){
    if(err){
     return throwError(err.reason);
    }else{
     console.log("Well the insert was just fine")
    }
  })
```

Comment: Will I have to manually clear the errors after they are resolved?

Comment: Nou the collection will be clean when the user close the session.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation, in resume when we declare collections like this . `new Mongo.Collection(null);` thats means that the collection only exists on the client side (browser) and it will be not connected or synchronized  on the server side, so each time the user close the connection the collection will be empty

Comment: I've posted up what I ended up with, thanks for the assistance, this has gotten me a LOT further on working with meteor

Comment: @Yablargo awesome its look great

Answer (score 1):

There's a fantastic package to handle this sort of thing, and it deserves to be better known:

http://viewmodel.meteor.com/

It takes a little while to get your head round it, but once you use it you ever go back.